# Android LinearLayout Weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I make Android UI with LinearLayout.

There is a question for negative weigth in Linear Layout

1. [weight ratio is 1:4:2:4:2:4:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y78j6.png)
   [image]
2. [weight ratio is 1:4:2:4:2:4:-5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb27g.png)
   [image]
3. weight ratio is -5:4:2:4:2:4:1 and [weight ratio is 1:4:2:4:2:4:-5] are same.
   (Sorry for this... I cannot upload more than two links...)

I understand result of first ratio and second ratio.

First ratio elements are all positive, so all components are good.

Second ratio elements contains negative element.
The last element is negative, so some back part is disappear.

Third ratio elements contains negative element.
The first element is negative.
I think that some front part must be disappear. But in this case, also some back part is disappear.

How can I make some front part is disappear?

Comment: you must care about weightSum of parent . addition of all weight of child view must be equal to parents  weightSum . and if you are applying  weight for height then all child's views height  must be set to 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you set the weight ratio as negative. If you want to disappear some part, you can set the weight ratio as 0.